# Python : Evaluating string of python code

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to create a Python script generation tool that creates Python files based on certain actions. For example:

```
action = "usb" # dynamic input to script
dev_type = "3.0" # dynamic input to script

from configuration import config
if action == "usb": 
       script = """
             #code to do a certain usb functionality
             dev_type = """ + dev_type + """
             if dev_type == "2.0"
                 command = config.read("USB command 2.0 ")
                 proc = subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)

             elif dev_type == "3.0":
                 command = config.read("USB command 3.0 ")
                 proc = subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)
             """

elif action == "lan":
     script = """
               #code to run a certain lan functionality for eg:
               command = config.read("lan command")
               proc = subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                       stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)
               """
with open("outputfile.py", w) as fl:
    fl.writelines(script)
```

The actual script generator is much complex.
I generate the "outputfile.py" script in my local machine inputting the action to the script and then deploy the script generated to remote machines to record the results. This is part of a larger framework and I need to keep this execution format.

Each "script" block uses a config.read function to read certain variables required for it to run from a config file. "command" in the above example.

My actual frame work has some 800 configurations in the config file - which I deploy on the remote machines along with the script to run. So there is a lot of extra configurations in that file that may not be required for a particular script to run and is not very user friendly.

What I am looking for is based on the "script" block that get written to the output file - create a custom config file that contains only the config that is required for that script to run.

For example if action is "lan", the below script block get written to the output file

```
script = """
         #code to run a certain lan functionality for eg:
         command = config.read("lan command")
         proc = subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)
         """
```

What I want is only the "lan command" in my custom config file.

My question is :
How do I evaluate the "script" block (inside triple quotes) to know which config are been used in that code and then to write that config to my custom config file when I write to output file ?

There could be multiple if conditions inside the "script" block also. I do not want config for "USB command 2.0" and "USB command 3.0" in the custom config file if the action = "usb" and dev_type  = "3.0"

Of course I cannot execute the code inside the "script" block - and then intercept config.read() function to write the config that got called to my custom config file. Is there a better way to do it ?

Comment: Are the commands separated by a fixed line? Or is it e.g. always a string "command" and a string "proc" ?

Comment: It is separated by fixed line.  I didn't understand what you mean by string "proc"

Comment: I meant `proc = subprocess....`, is there something to uniquely identify the commands in the file? e.g. are always two lines used for a single command? or are they separated by an empty line, or by a line of hashtags, etc. Could you show some raw commands in the file?

Comment: If all config extractions are on the form `command = config.read(_param_name_)`, and if none of the param names contain a double quote (`"`), you could easily use a regex to extract them from the script...

Comment: @Serge Ballesta The problem with that I cannot extract only the required config using regex in case action is "usb" - where there is a dynamic if-else check for dev_type is happening based on value of dev_type

Comment: Then don't do that. `ast` module could help in parsing the generated code, but IMHO you'd better have the same tool to generate both the script and the config.

Comment: I'm quite sure it's an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).